# How can I run GeoServer without the web frontend?

Tags: java, jetty, geoserver, wfs

I am considering switching my applications existing WFS/WMS "SDK" to GeoServer. However my application has a few special requirements.

- I must remain in control full of the applications entry point (main(...)).
- I cannot introduce any additional interfaces (such as the GeoServer GUI).

Essentially my application just needs an SDK which exposes our data over an HTTP "/wfs" path. We need to avoid any other interfaces or code being added or exposed. This is unfortunately an unavoidable requirement. Also, until now I have little experience in the GeoServer source code as we have been using a different Toolset. I am of course combing through the source, but am having trouble finding the right classes to get started.

In our existing SDK, I am able to programmatically create a Jetty server with a WFS Servlet assigned to our desired path. One class is provided during the Servlet initialisation which handles communication between our code, and the Servlet.

In order to get a similar setup using GeoServer, I am assuming:

- I must add org.geoserver.gs-wfs to my pom.xml dependencies
- I must run my own Jetty server in my Main function, and programmatically add the WFS module somehow

I do not yet know:

1. How to initialise and add the gs-wfs module to my own programatically created Jetty server
2. How to get a shared instance of the Catalog to add / remove the configured data

With specific focus on points 1 and 2 above, how do I initialise an instance of "just" the GeoServer WFS endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you're taking is too complicated (besides, there is no WFS servlet to start with)... the GeoServer war is the packaging of a modular application, with a selection of modules of common usage included in it.

If you want to remove the GUI you simply go into the packaged war file, and remove any jar that starts with "gs-web". Since you want full control, you probably want to remove also the administrative REST interface, thus remove also all jars starting with "gs-rest". That should get you close to an application that can start, and can run.

I say "close" because this operation is not commonly attempted, and there might be some unintended cross-module dependency preventing it to work.

Another possibility is to check-out GeoServer, get into `src/web/ap` (or clone it) and edit the `pom.xml` file, removing all dependencies you don't want... rebuild and you'll get a minimized war file with only the necessary jars.

Comment: Thanks, there are a few nice hints in there! Regarding the complexity, I am aware this is not the common usage, but it is the only option for us if we are going to adopt Geoserver. The other option is quite simply to stick with our existing WFS SDK which has this behaviour (Luciad Fusion). Regarding the use of source code, it is a delicate topic for us too due to the GPL (commercial project, usage of binaries vs source etc.).

I will see how much I can strip down the source. If I can get it working with just mvn dependencies, it will at least be a good contribution to the Geoserver docs..

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer is a lot more complex than just a pick and mix bag of jars. If you want to create a single jar WFS server you will need to start with a copy of the specification and probably an understanding of how [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) (the underlying library of GeoServer) works, and about a year or two of development time.

Or you could [read the GeoServer manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/)  and [turn off the GeoServer GUI](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/config.html#disable-the-geoserver-web-administration-interface). Then all you need to do is master the [REST API](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/index.html#rest) to load data into it.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that GeoServer is not just a "mix bag of jars". I was rather more hoping a well structured application who's Maven Dependencies are reliable. We already have the functionality we need with a commercial WFS provider, I am looking for an open source alternative. We cannot just turn of the interface, we need control over the application lifecycle, and would also have to exclude the rest API too. Our projects are subject to external certification requirements which we cannot avoid.

Comment: " rather more hoping a well-structured application who's Maven Dependencies are reliable"... GeoServer uses a modular architecture with dependencies management, you just need to alter its poms to get a subset of the core functionality. But then you say above you cannot do that due to GPL ... confusing...

Comment: Please do not think that I am deliberately trying to make my own life difficult. We would like to use GeoServer but if we cannot do it legally, then we cannot do it at all. I am trying to find a solution which will be acceptable to my license compliance department. According to them, anything to do with modifying source code is not ok, but a dependency on the binaries is. Hence, if we can add maven dependencies to our existing code, it is fine. Modifying the source POM and not declaring it as modified source is likely a license violation, and is not a risk my company would accept.

Comment: For posterity and to help others understand the GPL concerns and why doing anything with GPL licensed source code is a concern for comercial projects. An example of why our company is careful with GPL is the "CoKinetic and Panasonic" case. Incorrect handling of GPL source or Binaries can cost millions: https://wptavern.com/cokinetic-systems-pursues-100-million-gpl-license-violation-case-against-panasonic-avionics